# MS Chart Control showing blank when rowsource contains a WHERE Clause

Tags: charts, controls

First time poster and new to MS ACCESS. I am using MS ACCESS 2002-2003 database format. 
I have a Mainform in which I have a tabbed control. In one of the tabs, I have a subform where I put another tabbed control. In one of those tabs, I have a combobox that has a list of categories and I am trying to pass that value to a MS Chart control using VBA. The chart will update (it will show all categories) as long as there is no WHERE clause . If I remove the variable from the WHERE clause and type a VALUE in, it still does not work. When I run Debug.Print strSQLPIE. The strSQLPIE value shows the SQL statement and the WHERE clause correctly. However, Chart keeps showing up as blank. If i copy that SQL statement and put it in a new query, the query runs fine.

I have netted the issue down to the WHERE clause of the SQL statement in the ROWSOURCE property of the chart control. What am i missing?

Here is the code:

```
Dim DB As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strSQLSB As String ' subform datasheet sql
Dim strSQLPIE As String ' chart control sql
Dim SelCatStr As String ' combobox for categories
Dim SelYrStr As String ' not being used for now
Dim SelYrMtStr As String ' not being used for now
SelCatStr = Me.PIEChart.Value ' combobox selected value
'SelYrStr = Me.SelectYear.Value ' not being used for now
'SelYrMtStr = Me.SelectYearMonth.Value ' not being used for now

strSQLSB = "SELECT UNIONMASTER.ByMonth, UNIONMASTER.Category, UNIONMASTER.Category1, UNIONMASTER.AdjustedAmount " & _
"FROM UNIONMASTER " & _
"WHERE UNIONMASTER.Category1= '" & SelCatStr & "';" THIS UPDATES THE DATASHEET IN ANOTHER SUBFORM IN THE SAME TAB CORRECTLY ON CHANGE OF COMBOBOX.

strSQLPIE = "SELECT UNIONMASTER.Category1, Sum(UNIONMASTER.AdjustedAmount) AS TotalSpent " & _
"FROM UNIONMASTER " & _
"WHERE UNIONMASTER.Category1= '" & Me.PIEChart.Value & "';"
```

I TRIED USING SelCatStr and Me.PIEChart.Value in the WHERE CLAUSE and it still down not work. I even tried typing in a value and it still does not work. The debug window shows the SQL correctly and the where clause correctly, but the chart shows up as blank as long as the WHERE clause is there.

```
Me.PIESubform.Form.RecordSource = strSQLSB
Me.[PIESubform].Form.Requery

Debug.Print strSQLPIE
Me.[CatChart].RowSource = strSQLPIE
Me.[CatChart].Requery
```

I think the problem has to do with the WHERE clause in the rowsource setting of the CHART. As i said, when I remove the where clause, the chart shows correctly for all categories, the moment i stick the WHERE clause, with a VALUE or with a variable, it shows blank.

The chart works if i use this:

```
strSQLPIE = "SELECT UNIONMASTER.Category1, Sum(UNIONMASTER.AdjustedAmount) AS TotalSpent " & _
"FROM UNIONMASTER " & _
"GROUP BY UNIONMASTER.Category1 ;"

Me.CatChart.RowSource = strSQLPIE
Me.CatChart.Requery
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You may missing 'GROUP BY' clause in your query. Your query should be like this.

```
strSQLPIE = "SELECT UNIONMASTER.Category1, " &_ 
    "Sum(UNIONMASTER.AdjustedAmount) AS TotalSpent " & _
    "FROM UNIONMASTER " & _
    "WHERE UNIONMASTER.Category1= '" & Me.PIEChart.Value & "';" &_
    "GROUP BY UNIONMASTER.Category1 ;"
```